# SELECT MySQL using Sql Developer

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, mysql-workbench

I managed to connect to MySQL DB via Sql Developer following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89696/how-do-you-connect-to-a-mysql-database-using-oracle-sql-developer). MySQL DB shows and I can expolre tables via the navigator. However, I could not run SELECT statement to show any of these tables. In MySQL workbench I used to use :

```
use [database_name]
```

Then, run select statement in that database. But in Sql developer, I am not sure what should I add to the statement to make it work. I have tried the following:

```
select *
from [table_name].[database_name];
```

It does not work. I found this [tutorial](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/migrating-mysql-table-using-oracle-sql-developer-15), but nothing is mentioned about simple select statement. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Your queries are not MySQL syntax.

Comment: Shouldn't your query be `select *
from [database_name].[table_name];`? remove the `@` symbol

Comment: If you actually write the `[` and `]` these must be excluded too. That is SQL server syntax. In MySQL special keywords are escaped with `\``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, except MySQL specific commands; all other standard SQL commands like `SELECT`,`INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE` should work just fine using SQL Developer. but per your posted query, it looks total strange.

Your query

```
select * from [table_name]@[database_name];
```

1. remove that `@` sign.
2. you should qualify like `database_name.table_name`.
3. Unless it's a typo, remove those `[]` as well from your query
   statement.

Your query should look like

```
select * from database_name.table_name;
```

Comment: This statement works fine when the SQL worksheet is MySQL worksheet. What I need is to write script in SQL developer that combines both DB's (oracle and MySQL). So I Open Oracle DB worksheet in SQL developer and write SELECT statement normal querying oracle DB. But in this worksheet when I write SELECT statement querying MySQL DB, I get "table or view does not exsit". The same statement works fine in MySQL DB worksheet. When I try to add '@' considering that it's remote DB, I get "connection description for remote database not found"!  -  All above is in SQL Developer

Answer (score 1):

You can always write your SQL including database as well, in the form of:

```
database.tablename
```

such as:

```
select * from wordpressdb.usertable where username="someone"
```

Comment: This statement works fine when the SQL worksheet is MySQL worksheet. What I need is to write script in SQL developer that combines both DB's (oracle and MySQL). So I Open Oracle DB worksheet in SQL developer and write SELECT statement normal querying oracle DB. But in this worksheet when I write SELECT statement querying MySQL DB, I get "table or view does not exsit". The same statement works fine in MySQL DB worksheet. When I try to add '@' considering that it's remote DB, I get "connection description for remote database not found"!  -  All above is in SQL Developer

Comment: I think you are mixing up the ideas a bit. When you write an SQL query, it is sent to a server, which responds to it. Hence, you cannot send a query to a server and expect another server to answer it, even partially. What you explain would be possible with cluster systems, but not in mixed environments, ie, you can ask a cluster master of an oracle cloud and get answers derived from other oracle slaves, and same goes with mysql clusters, but as far as I know, a mysql/oracle mixed cluster is not possible. What you need to do is query both servers separately and combine the results in code.