# Connect to Databricks SQL Warehouse using Oracle SQL Developer, with JDBC driver

Tags: mysql, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, databricks

I've read: [How do you connect to a MySQL database using Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89696/how-do-you-connect-to-a-mysql-database-using-oracle-sql-developer)

---

I want to connect to my Databricks SQL Warehouse using Oracle SQL developer. So I:

- went to "Oracle SQL Developper > Tools > Preferences... > Database > Third Party JDBC Drivers > Add Entry..." and selected the Databricks JDBC Driver jar I [downloaded](https://www.databricks.com/spark/jdbc-drivers-download).
- repeated the process for the [MySQL JDBC driver](https://packages.atlassian.com/content/groups/public/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.30/) jar.
  [image]
- Now when I create a "New Connection", I see MySQL and Oracle as options in the "Database Type" combo-box, but no Databricks.

[image]

I'm also able to use the same Databricks JDBC Driver file in DBeaver and connect successfully.

Am I missing some step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported. I wish I had a better answer, but we hard-code the list of allowed JDBC drivers we support. And they match the list of databases our 'Migrate to Oracle' code path have been tested for.

Not enough Databricks customers are asking us to help them migrate to Oracle, yet.

Comment: Looking at your title I'll just accept this answer. :-). I suspect no one will ever ask Oracle to support migration from Databricks/Spark to Oracle (unless they had no idea what Databricks was and started using it). As they serve completely different functions.

Comment: exactly @Kashyap so that's why there's no support there, doesn't make sense

Comment: well, for someone who's familiar with the SQL Developer GUI, it would be good to be able to connect to Databricks using SQL Developer instead of learning a new tool like DBeaver/... I.e. use SQL Developer as a simple JDBC client. It is the standard JDBC driver/protocol so I would guess the reason to not support it would be non-technical.

Comment: @Kashyap correct - it's not our intent to provide a tool for just any ole database/data source - it's made to be best-of-breed specifically for Oracle DB (and also TimesTen in-memory db)